# OpenShift/MySQL error: lower_case_table_names error when migrating from OS X to OpenShift

Tags: mysql5.5, openshift-online-2

Ok, so I have dumped a MySQL 5.x database from an OS X instance, and am having problems importing the database into the OpenShift MySQL 5.5 container.  My tables are Camel-case (eg "tblAccounts") but the script is throwing errors like "cannot find table tblaccounts".

I believe that MySQL's lower_case_table_names flag is set to 2 on OS X.  And I was able to do a rhc set env command to change this variable from 0 to 2 on OpenShift.  I keep getting the missing table error.

I have tried multiple combinations of this flag, and have tried to reload the db from scripts created using mysqldump and MySQL Workbench, and I haven't found a clean approach where this error does not appear.  Am running out of ideas on how to do this cleanly.  Any suggestions?  Thanks,

fc

Comment: It's best practice to use [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for database object names.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late -- but for anyone else having this problem.

MariaDB will change `lower_case_table_name` from 2 to 0 when it starts up, if it sees that it's on a case-sensitive file system:

> `[Warning] lower_case_table_names was set to 2, even though your the file system '/var/lib/mysql/' is case sensitive.  Now setting lower_case_table_names to 0 to avoid future problems.`

I assume mysql does the same thing (being that it's forked from it).

You can set it to `1` and it'll take, however.  For me (also migrating from MacOS), I was able to do this after I had loaded my databases. and it worked fine ... but that seems to have gone against the documentation as to the difference between `1` and `2`.  If mysql isn't happy with that, you might have to blank your database, set it to `1`, and then re-load your data.